# How to get the cumulative sum of numpy array in-place

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cumsum

I want to compute the integral image. for example

```
a=array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)])
b = a.cumsum(axis=0)
```

This will generate another array b.Can I execute the `cumsum` in-place. If not . Are there any other methods to do that

Comment: I am not sure what output value you expect if not an array. Could you please precise?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to pass the argument `out`:

```
np.cumsum(a, axis=1, out=a)
```

OBS: your array is actually a 2-D array, so you can use `axis=0` to sum along the rows and `axis=1` to sum along the columns.

Comment: Is this the same to  a=np.cumsum(a,axis=1). How can I confirm the  `a` is the original one

Comment: @Samuel [in the documentation it states](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) that this function returns a new array, but I don't know how to check if it is the same object, for other objects we could use `hash()`, but np.ndarrays are unhashable...

Comment: It can be confirmed by the address of `a.data`. I have confirmed that it's in-place in your way thanks

Comment: @Samuel good to know this... I've been using `.data` in Cython but I never thought of using it for other purposes

Comment: @Samuel - Don't use `a.data` for this.  It will only work in a very limited number of cases (e.g. what you're doing where the same array is returned, instead of a new array that shares the same data).  Use `numpy.may_share_memory` instead.

Answer (score -3):

Try this using numpy directly `numpy.cumsum(a)` :

```
a=array([(1,2,3)])
b = np.cumsum(a)
print b
>>array([1,3,6])
```